# I'm looking for help in using ILO (instrumentation library for oracle) by Method-R. Is anyone familiar with that?

Tags: oracle, instrumentation

I've installed the ILO on the DB, and could use some examples on how to turn it on/off, and how to turn it on/off for specific packages.
Any help would be useful.  I've checked YouTube, and even Method-R and can't find any extensive examples to follow.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic] before posting  question

Answer (score 2):

ILO, the “Method R Instrumentation Library for Oracle,” is an open-source instrumentation framework. The main thing it’s built to do is the example shown at https://method-r.com/ilo/: you call `BEGIN_TASK()`, execute your application function, and then call `END_TASK()` at all the places where your code can terminate.

Of particular interest is the package `ILO_TIMER`, which gives you the functions `BEGIN_TIMED_TASK()` and `END_TIMED_TASK()`. These functions are distributed with empty bodies, but they are called by `BEGIN_TASK()` and `END_TASK()`, respectively. The intent is that you can fill in the `ILO_TIMER` function bodies with code you write, to, for example, persist information about selected application function executions.

If you poke around the contents of the zip file a little bit, you'll see a `doc` directory with a file called `START_HERE.html`. If you’ll browse from there, you’ll find documentation for a few dozen procedures and functions that ILO gives you. The `Package Ilo_Task` page contains a lot more detail about how to use ILO.

Comment: Hi Cary, thank you for your response.  I've read all the documentation, and still have questions on how to implement the ILO successfully.  By that I mean, we've put the calls into place, but when we execute the code, we're getting lots of other procedures calls in the same trace files.  I guess I could use some guidance on how to do it right.  I was hoping to fins a tutorial in YouTube, but I don't see any, at least not with what I'm looking for.  If there is any training videos out there, I'd love to see them.  Thanks for all your work with ILO.  Gary Frechette